# Spyder in anaconda is slow over x2go

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I use `Spyder` both from `anaconda2` and `anaconda3` via `x2go client` from my Mac to our cluster where both versions of anaconda are installed.

The problem is that `Spyder` is extremely slow to the limit of being unusable.

Can anyone suggest what to do and source of the problem? Our SysAdmin doesn't have any idea why this is the case.

Running other software on our cluster via `x2go client` from my Mac works fine. It's only the `Spyder` from `anaconda2` and `anaconda3` virtual environments is terribly slow.